# Unable to access Resources file in c sharp program after importing project

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013

Hi I have been working on a school project recently in visual studio using c sharp. Some of the files had become corrupted, I'm not sure why and the file structure was all messed up so I decided to create a new project and import the existing good code into the project.

After some cleaning up the project almost runs but fails when trying to access the Resource file:
`this.pictureBox1.Image = global::Coursework.Properties.Resources.PictureOne;`
This is definitely the correct path, I wrote it using auto completion and the PictureOne image is definitely in the Resources file.

At this point and I get the error:
An unhandled exception of type 'System.Resources.MissingManifestResourceException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

The error occurs at any time of trying to access the resources file. I noticed this in the error given which I thought was strange:
.. "Coursework.Properties.Resources.resources"... I don't know the second resources with the small "r" is referring to. I think it may be a namespace issue.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

You can follow this steps to resolve your issue.

1. Open the project that contains the localized form class where you receive the error message that is mentioned in the "Symptoms" section.
2. In Solution Explorer, expand all folders.
3. Right-click Form1.resX, and then click Properties.
4. In the Form1.resX Property Pages dialog box, expand Configuration Properties, and then click General under Managed Resources.
5. Change the Resource File Name property from $(IntDir)/  .Form1.resources to $(IntDir)/  . MyForm .resources, and then click OK.

Note MyForm is a placeholder for the class name of the form class that you localized.
Press CTRL+SHIFT+S to save the project. Press CTRL+SHIFT+B to build the solution. For more information, click the following article number to view the article in the Microsoft Knowledge Base:
824495 (http://support.microsoft.com/kb/824495/ ) FIX: You receive a "MissingManifestResourceException" error message when you add a linked resource in Visual Studio .NET 2003
Press F5 to run the application. The application runs, and the Form1 form is displayed.
Here is the detail information about your issue.
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/318603
KB: You may receive a "System.Resources.MissingManifestResourceException" error message when you access the .resources file of the form at run time